# Xpath expression not working in Scrapy

Tags: xpath, scrapy

Could you help me to undestand why the below Xpath expression does not work in Scrapy?

I get "Invalid Xpath"

```
//*[@id="Text_Body"//..[not(contains(@type,"text/css"))]/text()
```

The above Xpath expression is working in FireBug.

Comment: Could you post some `html`.. ? And also the Example you try to extract.

Comment: Looks like "]" should be placed after "Text_Body", but need XML and desired result to really know. "[" after ".." looks strange, too.

Comment: Maybe you mean //*[@id="Text_Body"][not(contains(../@type,"text/css"))]/text() (that's at least syntactically correct), but again, I need more data to really know what your intention is.

Comment: Your XPath expression is _not_ working in Firebug, because it is malformed, and will not be accepted by any XPath engine. So, why do you claim it works?

Comment: Post the HTML Please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a mistake in my XPath expression because I forgot a `]`: I should have written

```
//*[@id="Text_Body"]//..[not(contains(@type,"text/css"))]/text()
```

I was able to make it working also in Scrapy with this reformulation:

```
//*[@id="Text_Body"]//text()[not(ancestor::style)]
```